# Multiple requests with axios without waiting for all of them to finish

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I know that I can do this

```
axios.all([
axios.get('/comments'),
axios.get('/images')
])
.then(axios.spread((comments, images) => {
// do something with both responses
});
```

But I don't want to wait for both requests to finish. For example if images finish before comments I want to start working with that data. What would be the right approach? Should I do as below?

```
axios.get('/images')
.then((images) => {
// do something with images
});

axios.get('/comments')
.then((comments) => {
// do something with comments
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided should work fine as javascript has async execution and thus data should bind as the response comes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244989/multiple-requests-with-axios-without-waiting-for-all-of-them-to-finish-in-an-arr  How about this?