# Multiple requests with axios without waiting for all of them to finish in an array list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

```
taskList.push(
    const data = {
        url: 'http://${requestUrl}?${argsString}',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            Authorization: signature //,
            //'Content-Length': buffer.length
        },
        method: 'POST',
        data: buffer
    }
            return axios(data)
        )

try {
        const data = await Promise.all(taskList)
        const res = data.map(d => d.data)
        console.log(res)
        //ctx.state.data = res
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        throw e
    }
```

How to do not wait all requests finish, because all finish needs too long time. If any request finish, I print it out, it will be very fast for users.

Comment: No need to use Promise.all() , just add a `then()` to each request

Comment: I  am sorry that I didn't get your question. The above comment by @charlietfl is a solution too. What you are doing is making all the asynchronous requests at a time. Putting them with their own `then()` will make them independent.

Answer (score 2):

In case each response should be logged as soon as it's completed, it should be:

```
const responses = await Promise.all(taskList.map(async task => {
  const { data } = await task;
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

To run each Promise just add a `.then()` to each of one them or to the `Promise.all`, however you will not be able to `.map` the data after:

```
try {
    const data = Promise.all(taskList).then(() => console.log('finished'));
    // this will not wait to run, so data will be probably undefined
    const res = data.map(d => d.data)
    ...
```

So I'd suggest following the pattern and waiting for them to finish.

If it's taking too long maybe you should try improve the performance of the response in the back-end if that's possible.

Comment: ```TypeError: data.map is not a function``` Because, data has no value yet